# Map shows multiple markers (overlays)

Tags: android, maps, openstreetmap, marker, osmdroid

I'm using osmdroid API for maps in my project.

Below is the code I wrote to put an overlay(marker) on selected location.

If I click on map to select any location, it puts an overlay there, but if I tap on map again to select any new location, it shows a new overlay over there (it should) but **it doesn't remove the overlay from previous location**.

So if I select 10 locations, it shows 10 overlays!

My question is, how to remove previously put overlays when a new location is selected?

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    int actionType = ev.getAction();
    switch (actionType) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Projection proj = mMapView.getProjection();
            IGeoPoint loc = proj.fromPixels((int)ev.getX(), (int)ev.getY());
            String longitude = Double.toString(((double)loc.getLongitudeE6())/1000000);
            String latitude = Double.toString(((double)loc.getLatitudeE6())/1000000);

            GeoPoint mypointicon = new GeoPoint(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude());
            final ArrayList<OverlayItem> items=new ArrayList<>();
            items.add(new OverlayItem("Here", "Sample Description", mypointicon));
            this.mMyLocationOverlay = new ItemizedIconOverlay<>(items,
                    new ItemizedIconOverlay.OnItemGestureListener<OverlayItem>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onItemSingleTapUp(final int index, final OverlayItem item) {

                            return true;
                        }
                        @Override
                        public boolean onItemLongPress(final int index, final OverlayItem item) {

                            return false;
                        }
                    }, mResourceProxy);
            this.mMapView.getOverlays().add(this.mMyLocationOverlay);
            mMapView.invalidate();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Longitude: "+ longitude +" Latitude: "+ latitude , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Comment: You are still using Map API V1?

Comment: yes @Xcihnegn how can I remove previous overlays? I tried overlay.setVisibility(); but doesn't help

Comment: `itemizedOverlay.clear();` can do clear before next draw?

Comment: @Xcihnegn doesn't work! `clear()` method is not compatible with `itemizedOverlay`

Comment: You could find suitable api for `clear` before draw next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you have to manage your map overlays.

You could add an overlay: this.mMapView.getOverlays().add(this.mMyLocationOverlay);

So you also can remove it: this.mMapView.getOverlays().remove(index);

And you can remove all of them: this.mMapView.getOverlays().clear();

Comment: I searched and found `getOverlays.clear();` but couldn't figure out how to use it. Your answer helped me a lot. Thanks!